# “Target Audiences” property not visible in web part tool pane

Tags: audience-targeting

Environment: SharePoint 2010 CU: December

In SharePoint page --> web parts the “Target Audiences” property not visible in web part tool pane.

I tried IISRESET, restart of the machine as well as mentioned in some MS forums, but it didn’t fix it.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Which web part?

Comment: All the web parts

Comment: Are you on Foundation or Server? Can I verify you are looking for this property in the right place, in the Advanced section beneath the "Import Error Message" property?

Comment: Server ...Yes, we were looking at the right property. We have resolved it now, It was a user error :(  check my comment below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

By mistake we had a "-" char in the word "Culture" in web.config

Long version:

- We were implementing custom audience Runtime Filter to enable targetting for Anonymous users and we replace the OOTB "Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager" runtime filter with our custom audience Runtime Filter
- When making the entry into the web.config for our audience runtime filter, by mistake the the below line had a "-" char in the word Culture (like "Cul-ture") (our Change control system added the char "-" for a new line break!)

```
<RuntimeFilter
    Assembly="MyLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d532cf2904af4ae"
    Class="AnonymousAudiencesRuntimeFilter"
    BuilderURL="audience_chooser.aspx" />
```

Comment: @Shoban: You found a bug in the markdown editor, that's why it wasn't working as expected. Putting in something before the code seems to fix it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible

Comment: Its not resolved for me i don't see Cul- in my web.config....

Answer (score 2):

As Kishork noted, this particular issue was related to a custom audience filter. Just wanted to add that we've seen this same issue several times in our Sharepoint 2010 environment after using Metalogix to move content, or running various jobs. The initial symptom is the same - the target audience property isn't visible when editing a web part.

Running iisreset won't do the trick. I've seen several posts in various forums where admins have resorted to re-provisioning the User Profile Service application, which will work, but the solution in our environment has been pretty simple.

Just add a space, or any other small change, to web.config and save.

Not sure why this works, but try this if you ever run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Under List Settings > Audience Settings, do you have audiencing enabled for that list?

http://screencast.com/t/yKRWqXAxcI

Comment: His issue is with Target Audiences on Web Parts, not on lists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the solution for this problem. Was frustrated and got more confused with these misleading answers posted on the internet. Just follow these steps:

> Central Admin -> Web Application General Settings -> Select your Web
>   App (on which your site collection is hosted) -> Click on Service
>   Connections from the top ribbon -> Check the User Profile Service
>   Connection and save changes.

This should display the Target Audience property on your web part's Advanced property.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem because the App Pool associated with the User Profile service was not started.  Starting it and refreshing the site corrected the issue.

Here's an MSDN forum with some other step-by-step solutions.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2ca9ea59-b7ce-42fc-aed1-2224df5572a6/target-audience-web-part-property-is-missing-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this issue recently using a simple disable/enable trick:

(We confirmed all User Profile Services were running and were associated to the Web Application)

1. In Central Admin, go to Application Management and click 'Configure Service Application Associations'
2. In your web application row, click the application proxy group to show the associations.
3. Uncheck “User Profile Service Application” and hit OK.
4. Perform an IISRESET.
5. Reload the CA page and check the box again.

Your web parts should now immediately show the Target Audience property.